# Jquery Dialog No button

Tags: jquery-selectors

My problem is, I have a jquery dialog with buttons yes and no.

What I would like to do is when the user clicks on no, the dialog displays 
another content in a hidden class and the user clicks no again it closes the dialog.

I have tried finding solutions to this but cant find any.

This is what I have so far but aint working:

```
"No": function() {
    $("#dialog").html($("#cool"));
    if ($("#cool") == true) {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I have so far but aint working:                                                 "No": function() {
                        $("#dialog").html($("#cool"));
                        if($("#cool") == true)
                        {
                          $(this).dialog("close");
                        }

Comment: @pumba, after formatting your code, I'd say you're probably missing a call to `html()` in your second line, and I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve with the `if` clause.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi with the if I am checking if the id cool is visible then the following click must close the dialog.

Comment: @pumba, well... that's not the right way to do it. You probably already have that link, but I'd suggest you head to http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page and familiarize yourself with the API a little more. It will help in the long run.

Comment: Thanks Fred can you please provide and example of what I am trying to achieve will read the documentation when I am done with the project its due in no time please

Answer (score 0):

The code written in the question is not clear about the purpose.

Here is my understanding about this.

Initially, The "cool" div is hidden, but has some content which you want to display when the user clicks "No". The next time "No" is clicked, the dialog should be closed.

If this is what is required, then the below code should help.

```
"No": function() {
    if ($("#cool").is(":visible") == true) {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    } else {
        $("#cool").show();
    }
}
```